# How to append data to first non null cell in Column Google Sheets API V4 Java

Tags: java, append, google-sheets-api

I'm having trouble appending values to the first non-null cell in column c using Java in Google Sheets API V4.

```
    public void appendValues() throws IOException {
    ValueRange oRange = new ValueRange();
    oRange.setRange("B1");
    oRange.setValues(getDataToAppend());
    BatchUpdateValuesRequest oRequest = new BatchUpdateValuesRequest();
    oRequest.setValueInputOption("RAW");
    List<ValueRange> oList = new ArrayList<>();
    oList.add(oRange);
    oRequest.setData(oList);
    System.out.println("a");
    // TODO : BORKED!
    service.spreadsheets().values().append(spreadsheetId, "a", oRange).execute();
}

public List<List<Object>> getDataToAppend() {
    List<Object> data1 = new ArrayList<Object>();
    // TODO
    data1.add("a");
    List<List<Object>> data = new ArrayList<List<Object>>();
    data.add(data1);
    return data;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate).

> The following spreadsheets.batchUpdate request appends rows and
>   columns. The first request appends three empty rows to the end of the
>   sheet, while the second appends a single empty column.
>
> The request protocol is shown below. The Updating Spreadsheets guide
>   shows how to implement a batch update in different languages using the
>   Google API client libraries.

```
POST 
https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/spreadsheetId:batchUpdate
```